# How do I uninstall Ubuntu 11.10 from Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, flash, uninstall, drive, windows-xp

I installed a small 3gb Ubuntu partition just to delete some annoying files in XP, but I accidentally turned the XP partition into Swap and I can only boot in Ubuntu. I do not necessarily want to save any of the XP data, but just to uninstall ubuntu and reinstall XP from a USB flash drive (when I try doing that, I cannot see the Hard Drive to boot on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a notebook, you should change your BIOS boot-priority; and load into the Live Ubuntu image just like you did when you installed. The program you need to run is called `Gparted` not "Gpartet". When you open Gparted, you will be able to format your entire disk and re-install whatever operating system you want. If you are installing XP, instead of leaving the Hard Drive unallocated - - you could make the entire HDD NFTS (Windows Primary File System) to speed up the XP install. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this immediatly and let you know if it worked! You really are great people!

Comment: Should I change the flag of the partition to something else than boot?

Comment: I still cannot boot and cannot see the partition. I guess it's that mbr thing ad33l talked about.

Comment: @Alin You should modify your question to include these new circumstances. What happened when you put in your XP install disk?

Answer (score 0):

Insert Ubuntu Live CD and use GParted to format the disk.

Comment: I have an acer netbook, therefore, no optic unit. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: can I download GPartet from the ubuntu centre?

Comment: Yes, but is already availalbe when booting from live disk.

Comment: I just tried! Thanks! So, after I format the partition, I should be able to reinstall WinXP from a bootable flash drive, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

it's because windows can't read file systems other than FAT or NTFS and your hard drive doesn't have mbr anymore. you can daownload [partedmagic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=downloads) and bootable usb creator like [yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) make a bootable usb. boot from usb and fix your bootloader and partitions from partedmagic, then try to install windows again.

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful. I hope it works! :)

Comment: you're welcome. you didn't need to install ubuntu to fix windows problems in first place. you can make bootable usb-stick with tools like partedmagic, gparted, clonezilla, norton ghost, etc. to resolve these issues.

Comment: How do I fix the bootloader from partedmagic?

Comment: PartedMagic's live cd image includes super grub disk, it can be used for this job. Go to the extras menu on the PartedMagic's live cd. It sould be able to restore your windows boot loader. There are lots of other handy tools on PartedMagic you can use for partitioning, repair etc.

Comment: ok, I'll try. Please stay close, as I have no clue what I'm doing. Thank you!

Comment: I installed partedmagic from the iso link you posted, but I cannot find the extras menu. I do not have an optical unit, it's all on a netbook

Comment: no need to install anything, just make a bootable live usb with either of ubuntu or PartedMagic iso. boot your netbook with bootable usb-stick just created (change boot device order from bios setup). For PartedMagic, boot menu includes extras menu (screenshot: http://partedmagic.com/lib/exe/detail.php?id=screenshots&media=bootscreen.png). Otherwise, you can boot with default options and start GParted from desktop environment (screenshot: http://partedmagic.com/lib/exe/detail.php?id=screenshots&media=bootscreen.png); re-write partition table, format system drive, and set it boot flags on it.